# How to copy worksheet protection options?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm copying worksheet from one workbook to another using `IXLWorksheet.CopyTo` method and protection options are not copied. I think it is by design, but I need them to be copied.

```
private void CopyProtectionOptions(IXLSheetProtection source, IXLSheetProtection target)
{
    target.AutoFilter = source.AutoFilter;
    target.DeleteColumns = source.DeleteColumns;
    target.DeleteRows = source.DeleteRows;
    target.FormatCells = source.FormatCells;
    target.FormatColumns = source.FormatColumns;
    target.FormatRows = source.FormatRows;
    target.InsertColumns = source.InsertColumns;
    target.InsertHyperlinks = source.InsertHyperlinks;
    target.InsertRows = source.InsertRows;
    target.Objects = source.Objects;
    target.PivotTables = source.PivotTables;
    target.Scenarios = source.Scenarios;
    target.SelectLockedCells = source.SelectLockedCells;
    target.SelectUnlockedCells = source.SelectUnlockedCells;
}
```

Is there is a better way then just copy each flag "by-hand"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no better way.

You can't copy the full protection object because that includes the password which is encrypted.

Comment: Looks like you're right. This `CopyProtectionOptions` method would be very handy in ClosedXML API, not the client code.